# How to suppress in bash the printout on the screen upon subshell execution?

Tags: bash

This simplified script illustrates what I am after:

```
#!/bin/bash

( echo a; sleep 1; echo b; ) &>file.log &

return 0
```

I source the above script - I merely want to run subshell in the background, and to capture both its stdout and stderr in some log file.

However, when the subshell terminates, and when I execute some other command in the terminal, I am always getting on the screen the following example printout:

```
[1]+  Done                    ( echo a; sleep 1; echo b ) &> file.log
```

Is there any way to suppress such printout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to suppress such printout?

Disable job controlling.

Either execute `set +m` (or was it `set -m`, check docs) before *sourcing* the script.

Or just *execute* the script instead of sourcing it - job control is disabled in scripts (by default).

Comment: Thanks for a feedback! But is there a direct way to dump this unwanted printout somewhere (e.g. to /dev/null)? Such a solution would fit better

Comment: `But is there a direct way to dump this unwanted printout somewhere` No. You can redirect the whole shell output.